# boolean equation set complement

Tags: algorithm

If I have a n bit boolean equation set, is there any easy way or algorithm to get is complement set ?

For example say I have a 3 bit boolean equation set {110, 001}, is there any easy way to get is complement set under U(permutation on 3 bit) that is {000,010,011,100,101,111} ?

Thank you!

Comment: My key point is when n is increase, the algorithm seems exponential ?

Comment: The number of elements in U grows exponentially with n, which means the number of elements in the complement will grow exponentially.

Comment: There is not way around the algorithm (any algorithm for this problem) being exponential in `n` (or, equivalently, linear in `O(2^n)`), where `n` is the number of bits.

Comment: are you really asking if you can get 2^n elements in less then 2^n steps?

Comment: Or is there any good algorithm to derive it's complement set representation, like x01 .. x represents any bits 0 or 1, can we derive such equation for the complement set ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run over whole U (from `0` to `2^x - 1` where x is number of bits) and omit the ones that you already have. You can convert them to numbers to make check for equality faster.

Comment: But when x is quite large, the algorithm is exponential ? Is there is a way to avoid it, or the problem is NPC ? Thank you!

Comment: @koko - The problem grows exponentially, but it is not NP-Complete.  Different concepts.

Comment: @koko ok, it is exponential. For me it looks like essentially fastest method, because how otherwise you can get those elements? If you had very big amount of numbers (for example all numbers have 1 set as one bit) you can pre-analyze them to be able to skip amount of cycles in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET[] = {6, 1}

for(i=0;i<N;i++) {
 if(!exists(SET)) {
  add(i, COMPLEMENT_SET)
 }
}
```

N = 2^n-1
Something like this...

Answer (score 0):

You could subtract your set from U.